# Initializing table with variable argument list

Tags: c++

In my code I want to be able to do

```
Table<double> tbl;
tbl.Create(2, 2, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
```

and via the constructor too

```
Table<double> tbl(2, 2, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
```

From my experience the use of ellipses (...) leads to several hard to trace bugs, so I've come up with the following to initialize my table:

```
void Create(size_t rows, size_t columns, T val0)
{
    ASSERT(rows * columns == 1);
    Create(rows, columns);
    _data[0] = val0;
}

void Create(size_t rows, size_t columns, T val0, T val1)
{
    ASSERT(rows * columns == 2);
    Create(rows, columns);
    _data[0] = val0;
    _data[1] = val1;
}

void Create(size_t rows, size_t columns, T val0, T val1, T val2)
{
    ASSERT(rows * columns == 3);
    Create(rows, columns);
    _data[0] = val0;
    _data[1] = val1;
    _data[2] = val2;
}
```

I think you get the idea. However, this becomes rather annoying if I want functions for say up to 50 elements. Not to mention the fact I'll have to write all these constructors too. Isn't there another way to handle this more elegantly?

EDIT: Maybe I should explain why I don't want to use ellipses (...) in this case. Let's consider the following code:

```
Table<double> tbl(2, 2, 1.5, 2.1, 3, 4.5);
```

The compiler interprets the 5th argument as type `int` and this is clearly not intended.

Answer (score 3):

Variadic templates and initializer lists might work:

```
struct Table
{
    std::vector<double> data;

    template <typename ...Args>
    Table(Args &&... args)
    : data({std::forward<Args>(args)...})
    {  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'd love to solve this without using C++11 features.

Comment: If you don't want to use `c++11` features, perhaps your best chance is to pass it an array of `double` (with its size) and initialize from that. Like `double tmp[] = {2, 2, 1.5, 2.1, 3, 4.5}; Table<double> tbl(tmp, 6);` Or write a macro that does that for you.

Comment: Pre-11 C++ was terrible for using raw C arrays. Variadic functions are very non-C++, as you don't have any type safety and it's impossible to tell that you're using them right.